# CSS user-select: Disable whitespace selection but allow text selection

Tags: css, selection

Is there any way to block selection of anything that isn't text? Like leftover `<div>` whitespace and `<img`s and such...

## Undesired selection

Disable this.
[image]
Sometimes click-drag / double-click then this happening is the only bitter reminder that you're not using a "native app".

## Desired selection

...but still allow this.
[image]

A clever way of applying `-user-select` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be a bit wary of this, because the MDN specs say explicitly

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

That being said, you could wrap the specific lines of text with inline elements (such as spans). Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jP7th/

```
<div>
    <span>hello</span><br/>
    <span>hi | yo | what's up</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
div span {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```